# Spree: different shipping charges based on city, state and country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm building e-commerce application using `spree`. I need to apply shipping charges according to user's city or state.

1. If a user is from a home city, let's say 'Mumbai'.

   - If order total is below Rs. 400 INR Shipping charges should be Rs. 40 INR.
   - If order is above Rs. 400 INR shipping should be free.
2. If a user is from a state 'Maharashtra' but not from 'Mumbai' city.

   - If Order total is below Rs. 600 INR Shipping charges should be Rs. 60 INR.
   - If order is above Rs. 600 INR shipping should be free.
3. If a user is from anywhere in India but not from 'Maharashtra' state.

   - If Order total is below Rs. 800 INR Shipping charges should be Rs. 80 INR.
   - If order is above Rs. 800 INR shipping should be free.

NOTE: Mumbai is city from Maharashtra state in India.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spree. Do you need to make these calculations in Rails and simply submit your shipping charge to spree?

Comment: @BrentEicher: Spree has this kind of provisions but as I'm new to spree so I'm looking for the suggestions in spree. :)